# Workflow: wait until item is updated

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, 2007

I have a SharePoint Designer workflow that updates a list item, in another list (not the list the workflow is attached to). I need to make sure the item is updated before I move to the next step. What is the recommended way to do this?

What I have used so far is "pause for 1 minute", which in practice can take several minutes. Is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a while loop which checks for the target item "Modified" property with a respect to condition:

1. Store the system date time before you are executing the item update.
2. Check if Target Item Modified > #1
3. Exit

Comment: I should have said that I am using SharePoint Designer (2007). I don't have a while loop.